# Is it a good idea to use GenerationType.SEQUENCE with Hibernate in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, primary-key

I read that Hibernate enforces an extra query upon entity creation even when using the IDENTITY strategy, hence killing on MySQL some of the optimizations that would make it preferable over the "emulated" SEQUENCE strategy.

Hence, is it preferable to go for IDENTITY or SEQUENCE when using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Basically `SEQUENCE` is a really good strategy because it allows Hibernate to use some extra features (e.g. JDBC batch, other optimalizations, delayed execution of inserts).
But you cannot use this strategy in MySQL because it requires database sequences which is not supported in MySQL.
Hence, you have to choose another strategy or create sequence emulation.

*GenerationType.IDENTITY* approach is easy to implent and it uses an AUTO_INCREMENT columns.

*Sequence emulation* approach is a little bit more complicated at the beginning and only once.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/arieljannai/acc72888750b8167faad) is a good gist which will help you.

Comment: thank you for sharing the snippet but my question is more whether it is a good idea to use sequence on MySQL or not. Are there performances hit over Identity?